# Pass props only once from JS to CSS-in-JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-in-js

I'm working on a reusable sidebar, with React & CSS-in-JS with the @emotion/react library

I have a ReactComponent that returns something like this:

```
 return (
    <s.SidebarContainer 
        backgroundImage={backgroundImage} 
        isOpen={isOpen}>
        <s.TogglerContainer 
            onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} 
            isOpen={isOpen}>
        </s.TogglerContainer>
        <s.SidebarHeader 
        font={fonts.header}
        >
            {header}
        </s.SidebarHeader>
        <s.MenuContainer>{menuItemsJSX}</s.MenuContainer>
    </s.SidebarContainer>
)
```

As you can see, I attach the props to each style component.
And this is my style.js:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';


export const SidebarContainer = styled.div`
width: ${p => p.isOpen ? '18%' : '5%'} ;
background-image: 
linear-gradient(
    315deg,
    rgba(252,82,150,0.8) 0%,
    rgba(246,112, 98, 0.8) 74%),
    url(${p => p.backgroundImage}
);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
color: white;
position: relative; // Toggler
transition: .2s ease-in all;

@media (max-width: 576.97px){ 
    width: ${p => p.isOpen ? '80%' : '15%'} ;
}

@media (min-width: 577px) and (max-width: 992px){ 
    width: ${p => p.isOpen ? '30%' : '7%'} ;
}
`


export const SidebarHeader = styled.h3`
text-align: center;
height:10%;
margin-top: .5em;
letter-spacing: .1em;
font-size: 1em;
font-family: ${p => p.font};
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0em .3em;
`

export const TogglerContainer = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    
    &:after{
        ${p => p.isOpen ? `content:'<';`
                        : `content:'>';`}
        text-align:center;
        position:absolute;
        background-color: #E58C8A;
        background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #E58C8A 0%, #EEC0C6 74%);
        right:0;
        transform: translateX(12px);
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        margin-top:2em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color:rgb(19,15,64);
        box-shadow: 4px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        transition:  .2s ease-in box-shadow;
    }
    &:hover{
        &:after{
            box-shadow: 5px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            transition:  .2s ease-in all;
        }
    }

    `
```

I just put a part of code to avoid fill your display.
My question is:

> There's some way to send the props to .style.js file only once (through file instead through component), and then in .style.js file recive it and use it globally?

> For example, i want had something like this,

```
  <s.SidebarContainer 
    backgroundImage={backgroundImage} >
    <s.TogglerContainer 
        onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
```

(see what i removed `isOpen={isOpen}` )

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the prop to each styled component that depends on the prop.

Each styled component is a react component, and emotion will re-render the component when the props change, allowing you to [adjust the styles based on props](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#changing-based-on-props). It would not be possible to pass the `isOpen` state to only one styled component and share that state with the rest of the styled components because each component must receive the `isOpen` state via its own props.